# Error al llamar a método: no arguments reason

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un problema cuando intento llamar un método para que ejecute una función de otro método. cuando voy a compilar el programa me sale un error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

// Declared class ProjectPorStr
public class ProjectPorStr {
    // Declared Object Scanner; 
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Declaring the metohod menu
// And declaring menu items.
 public static void menu (String productNamesList[]) {
    String test = "";

    do {
        test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "a. Add items\n b. Show items\n c. Remove items\n x. Exit");

        if (test.equals ("a")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added items");
        }
        else if (test.equals ("b")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Showing items");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, productNamesList);
        }
        else if (test.equals ("c")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delet the items");
        }
        else if (test.equals ("x")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for user own system. See it soon!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try agen.");
        }
    }while(!test.equals("d"));
}   
    // Declaring the metohd call name
    // And declaring multiple variable
    // Reader, fileInput, fileOutput and the array name productNamesList has 50 items
    // Adding integer variable matchesCount, date, upcNumber, experDate, quantitySold, itemsPrices
    // Collect the data when the user enters the product number
    public static void name () {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileReader reader;
        Scanner fileInput;
        PrintWriter fileOutput;
        String productNamesList [] = new String [30],
        product, strLine, namesOfInputFile, namesOfOuputFile;

        int matchesCount = 0, date, upcNumber, experDate, quantitySold, itemsPrices;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name of the input file and add .txt: ");
        namesOfInputFile = keyboard.next();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name of the output file and add .txt: ");
        namesOfOuputFile = keyboard.next();

        // Input try
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(namesOfInputFile);
            fileInput = new Scanner (reader);

            while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                strLine = fileInput.nextLine();
                product = strLine;
                upcNumber = Integer.valueOf(strLine);

                if (upcNumber < 42) {
                    productNamesList[matchesCount] = product;
                    matchesCount += 1;
                } 
            }
            fileInput.close();
        }catch(IOException error) {
            System.out.print("File error " + error);
        }

        // Output try
        try {
            fileOutput = new PrintWriter(namesOfOuputFile);
            for (int i = matchesCount - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Product: " + productNamesList[i]);
                fileOutput.print(productNamesList[i]);
            }
            fileOutput.close();
        }catch(IOException error) {
            System.out.print("File error " + error);
        }
    }

    // The main function
    // Calling the matohd
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProjectPorStr myMenu = new ProjectPorStr();
        myMenu.menu();
        name();
  }
}
```

---

El error que le salda es el siguiente:

```
$ javac ProjectPorStr.java
ProjectPorStr.java:107: error: method menu in class ProjectPorStr cannot be applied to given types;
                myMenu.menu();
                      ^
  required: String[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

---

Si me pueden ayudar en esto le voy a dar la gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puedes ver en su declaración `public static void menu (String productNamesList[])` el método menu necesita como parámetro de entrada una lista.

En este caso cuando lo vas a ejecutar, no le estás enviando nada `myMenu.menu();`

Para que funcione tendrías que primero crear una lista y luego llamar el método pasándole esa lista.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProjectPorStr myMenu = new ProjectPorStr();
        String[] menuList = {"Carne", "Pescado", "Postre"};
        myMenu.menu(menuList);
  }
```

Comment: Ah vale entiendo, gracias. Tengo otra pregunta y si yo quiero que el parámetro de entrada que le estoy pasando recoja esa lista de un archivo externo que tenga. como lo puedo hacer ?

Comment: Por favor, si la respuesta te ha servido márcala como aceptada. Si tienes otra pregunta es mejor que no la hagas aquí, sí no que formules otra. Por darte una pista, para leer un fichero podrías usar la clase Scanner.

Comment: vale, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: de nada, acepta la respuesta para ayudar al resto de la comunidad (icono ✓ a la izquierda de la respuesta)